How can I make one character carry another character?
I'm trying to create a battle scene where one character is injured and must be carried off the field by a comrade. How can this be achieved without having to continuously reposition the wounded character? Both models already have armatures. I've seen YouTube tutorials where you can parent an object to a specific bone, but I'm not sure how to do this with two separate armatures. Any ideas?

Select the root/core/hips of the carried character and add a child of constraint to the bone.

Thanks. I will try this out.
